# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined AND Error: ERROR processing skip func

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

The error(s) I'm getting (while deploying, see end for code)

`Error: ERROR processing skip func of /home/amey/hardhat/hardhat-fund-me/deploy/01-deploy-fund-me.js:`

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ethUsdPriceFeed')`

When I click on the error, i'm taken to this line in 01-deploy-fund-me.js (in another file)

```
ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeed"]
```

here is the code i was trying to deploy

```
const { network, getNamedAccounts, deployments } = require("hardhat")
const {
    developmentChains,
    DECIMALS,
    INITIAL_ANSWER,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployment }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks...")
        await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: (DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER),
        })
        log("Mocks Deployed!")
        log("--------------------------------------------------------------")
    }
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. The solution to my problem was adding:

```
namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
        default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
        1: 0 // similarly on mainnet it will take the first account as deployer. Note though that depending on how hardhat network are configured, the account 0 on one network can be different than on another
    }
}
```

To the bottom of hardhat.config.ts

Source: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/blob/main/hardhat.config.js

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. If you log out the deployer variable with console.log(), it returns empty. This means the getNamedAccounts is not able to resolve an account. But if using mocks, the deployer variable returns an account number. If you hard-coded the deployer variable with your metamask account no in the hardhat.config.js file. It will return an unknown signer error. I am still stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are missing an important hardhat dependency "hardhat-waffle"
try

```bash
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
```

and in hardhat.config.js add

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

in your networkConfig the property "ethUsdPriceFeed" is defined. try to define it like the following

```js
export const networkConfig :networkConfigType= {

  4: {
    name: "rinkeby",
    ethUsdPriceFeed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e",
  },

  137: {
    name: "polygon",
    ethUsdPriceFeed: "0xF9680D99D6C9589e2a93a78A04A279e509205945",
  },
};
```